# Interpreting pvalue in the light of known power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, interpretation, statistical-power

I'm puzzled with the interpretation of a pvalue in the light of known power

- Let's say I study the association between a dichotomic variable (a treatment) and a quantitative one, which is my primary endpoint
- Let's say I know both the minimum clinically important difference (MCID) for the latter (and let's assume it is also the true treatment effect) and its expected variability in control population. Combining these informations, I can calculate the sample size needed per group (assuming the observations are independant) in order to controling beta at 20% ($SSN_{80}$).

Assuming the $SSN_{80}$ is recruited, then if $H_{1}$ is true, any of the following scenario is possible:

1. Any observed difference equal or superior to the MCID will yield a significant pvalue
2. Any observed difference inferior to the MCID **but** such as the computed statistic is superior to the critical region will also yield a significant pvalue

Scenario 1 and 2 happen 80% of the time: this is the power of the test

3. Any observed difference inferior to the MCID **and** such as the computed statistic is inferior to the critical region will yield a non significant pvalue

Scenario 3 happens 20% of the time: this is $\beta$

My questions are: in case of known power

- do scenario 1 and 2 have the same interpretation? That is, is the interpretation of a significant result the same, regardless the position of the point estimate compared to the one of the true effect?
- should/could scenario 3 be interpreted as "either there is no effect, either it is probably clinically meaningless"?

Thanks for your help